# How many diagonals does a regular $n$-sided polygon have?

Tags: combinations

I guess the answer is: $C(n,n-3)/2$ since for $n$-sided polygon,there are $n$ vertices, and for each vertex, it cannot form diagonal with the adjacent points and itself. So, each vertex can form $n-3$ points. And half of the vertices have repeated diagonals and we need to divide by $2$.

It holds true for quadrilateral and pentagon,but why it does not fit triangles?

Comment: Note that "vertex" is the singular, e.g. "This vertex is..." or "These vertices are...".  It's like "This matrix is...." and "These matrices are....".  The same applies to "vortex/vortices" and "helix/helices".  I corrected it in the posting.  But you should get $n(n-3)/2$, not $C(n,n-3)/2$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number you have computed, $C(n,n-3)/2$, which I am interpreting as $\binom{n}{n-3}/2$ though this doesn't coincide with your argument, is too large. A different way:

We can choose any two points, except adjacent points are not allowed. There are $\binom{n}{2}$ pairs of points and $n$ pairs of adjacent points, so the answer is $\binom{n}{2}-n$.

Comment: For clarification to those people reading and comparing answers, $\binom{n}{2} - n = \frac{n^2-n}{2} - \frac{2n}{2} = \frac{n^2-3n}{2} = \frac{n(n-3)}{2}$ and so both answers given agree.

Comment: But what's wrong with my reasoning?We just use different ways to think about the question.

Comment: @JimfyWindsy nothing's wrong with it as I said in my comment below. Just the final answer was incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning, which is correct, implies that the number of diagonals is
$$\frac{n(n-3)}2$$
and this fits for triangles, that have no diagonals.

Comment: But the OP wrote $\binom{n}{n-3}/2$.

Comment: This answer is a good use of the [handshaking lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) where there are $n$ vertices, each with degree $n-3$.  The result then follows immediately.

Comment: @MattSamuel: Well, they wrote $C(n,n-3)/2$, but their reasoning is correct.

Comment: @robjohn I agree.